# Passing XML parameter to a stored procedure via ASMX web service

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, asmx

I have a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure that has a signature like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcTRequest] 
   @Pxml xml, @ClientCode varchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

I'm tasked with writing an `.asmx` web service that will call this stored procedure. This is where I'm having a block.

If the parameter `@Pxml` is specified as string in the C# web method, we get

> *Server was unable to process request.*

Then tried `XmlText` as the type for `@Pxml`, which resulted in

> *Server was unable to process request. Method MyWebService.MyWebMethod can not be reflected. There was an error
>   reflecting 'PXml'. ->; There was an error reflecting type
>   'System.Xml.XmlText'. -> System.Xml.XmlText cannot be used as: 'xml
>   element'.*

What is the correct way to call this stored procedure from a C# web method? Please note that the `@Pxml` parameter will always be a well-formed XML.

The person that will be calling this web service is using Curl on a Unix system.

Though the requirement is an ASMX, if this can be implemented via WCF, can you please show me how with a piece of pseudo code? I'm not familiar with WCF yet.

Please help. Thank you.

UPDATE: This is how I call the SP

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string GetRequestID(string PXml, string clientcode)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        using (IDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader("ProcRequestID", PXml, clientcode))
        {
            return dr["RequestID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use a **string** on the ASMX interface (so the caller send you a string), but inside the ASMX web service, you define the `@PXml` parameter on the stored procedure call as `SqlDbType.Xml` ? I think that ought to work ....

Something along the lines of :

```
[WebMethod]
public void MyWebMethod(string input, string clientCode)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(your-connection-string-here))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ProcTRequest", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pxml", SqlDbType.Xml);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);

            cmd.Parameters["@Pxml"].Value = input;
            cmd.Parameters["@ClientCode"].Value = clientCode;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Since you're just calling the stored proc and not expecting a result set back - use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteReader`.

Also vitally important : tell ADO.NET that you're calling a **stored procedure**! That's what this line does:

```
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Otherwise, ADO.NET by default expects to get full inline SQL statement and might just not be able to parse and execute that ....